# How do I get data from this json field?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How are you doing?

I'm trying to get data from a json to show on a screen that should be like the image below. I'm able to get most of the data, except for one field coded as String which consists of the image and a description like this one:

```
"lessonText": "{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":{\"image\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64,(IMAGE CODE HERE)=\"}},{\"attributes\":{\"color\":\"#444444\"},\"insert\":\"(LESSON TEXT HERE)\"},{\"insert\":\"\\n\"}]}",
```

How do I extract data from here? I have tried to convert this to a Map but it is not working.

Thanks for the help!

[image: Desired screen]

Comment: The "image code" you point to is base64 of the actual bytes of the image. You can "decode" the base64 to the bytes of the image and then load the image from memory.

Answer (score 2):

Something in line with this should give you the image

```
// json string containing the base64 image string
String jsonString = "{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":{\"image\":\"data:image/png;base64,(IMAGE CODE HERE)=\"}},{\"attributes\":{\"color\":\"#444444\"},\"insert\":\"(LESSON TEXT HERE)\"},{\"insert\":\"\\n\"}]}";

// convert the string to a map structure
Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(jsonString);

// extract the image string
String imageString = json['ops'][0]['insert']['image'];

// extract the base64 string
var prefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
var imageBase64String = imageString.substring(prefix.length);

// decode the base 64 string
var bytes = base64Decode(imageBase64String);

// build the image widget from bytes
var imageWidget = Image.memory(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, use a combination of decoding the base64 string to bytes and then loading the image from memory. See the the relevant documentation for [`base64Decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/base64Decode.html) and [`Image.memory`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html). If you would like a full code sample just let me know and I would be happy to throw one together.

Note: you should run the `base64Decode` method asynchronously, as it may take some time to decode an entire image (especially on lower-end hardware).